# How to see Blazor component class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor, asp.net-blazor

While in Visual Studio, inside a blazor component (`.razor`) I have the following

```
<FooButton OnClick="OnClick" Enabled="Enabled">
    @ChildContent
</FooButton >
```

And I want to see what properties `FooButton` have and how it works.

Normally, with C# classes, you can press `F12` (or click `Go To Definition`) and see the properties, but with Blazor components, I can't.

F12 doesn't work and there is no `Go To Definition`.

With blazor, how can I do this `Go To Definition` thing?

## Edit:

Is this possible to do if the component isn't defined in my solution? For 3rd party components?

So of the components have alot of properties that aren't in the docs, and If I could do this, I would be able to understand better the component.

Answer (score 4):

if the `FooButton` is defined component in your solution

I use [Go TO All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to?view=vs-2019) shortcut `CTRL+,` or `CTRL+T`

and select the file with name `FooButton.razor` not `FooButton.g.razor` that's the generated file

*it may take 1 second patient to show required file*

Comment: This is a good answer, very helpful. The only down side is that It only works for components defined in your solution. Even though, upvoted!